# How to play MP4 in wpf?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, mediaelement

the most I managed so far was to reproduce the sound, without image

```
<MediaElement Name="myMediaElement" LoadedBehavior="Manual"
                          Margin="5"
                          Grid.Row="0"
                          Grid.Column="0"
                          ScrubbingEnabled="True"
                          Source="C:\Users\TheMagicTool Server\Downloads\myVideo.mp4"
                          />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does the video show up at all?
Just a hunch, try adding Height="200" Visibility="Visible" to the MediaElement.

```
<MediaElement Name="myMediaElement" LoadedBehavior="Manual"
                      Height="200" 
                      Visibility="Visible"
                      Margin="5"
                      Grid.Row="0"
                      Grid.Column="0"
                      ScrubbingEnabled="True"
                      Source="C:\Users\TheMagicTool Server\Downloads\myVideo.mp4"
                      />
```

Not sure if this'll help at all but worth a shot. MP4 should be supported.

Answer (score 0):

Change LoadedBehavior to "Play" worked for me.

```
<MediaElement Name="myMediaElement" LoadedBehavior="Play"
                      Height="200" 
                      Width="500"
                      Visibility="Visible"
                      Margin="5"
                      Grid.Row="0"
                      Grid.Column="0"
                      ScrubbingEnabled="True"
                      Source="Resources/2023-11-08 13-37-25.mkv"
                      />
```

**Edit:** I should also mention that logcialy it would be best to add the video to your Resources folder as a Content and set to Copy if Newer.